# How to add css transitions to js scroll in header?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have a header that appears when the page scrolls down. I am trying to add css transitions to make it fade in and out because I've read that using javascript for fading is not as efficient.

```
.header-wrapper {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
.header-wrapper.active {
     display:block;   
}
.header {
    background-color:#000;
    height:80px;
}
```

[Here is the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL9ro4gL/5/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    // if above 300 and doesn't have active class yet
    if (y > 300 && !$('.header-wrapper').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.header-wrapper').addClass('active');

    // if below 300 has still has active class
    } else if(y <= 300 && $('.header-wrapper').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.header-wrapper').removeClass('active');
    }
    });
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: You can transition numeric properties, in your case: `opacity`.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions are added with the css3 property `transition`.

One common reason for confusion: you can only transition properties that accept numeric values.  Thus, you can't transition between `display: block` and `display: none`.

However you *can* transition between `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` with:

`transition: 0.5s opacity`

That would look something like this:

```
.bottomMenu {
    ...
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
    ...
}
.bottomMenu.active {
     opacity: 1;   
}
```

For your particular case, I might recommend transitioning the height between `0` and `60px`.

For that you can use:

`transition: 0.5s height`

So:

```
.bottomMenu {
    ...
    height: 0;
    transition: 0.5s height;
    ...
}
.bottomMenu.active {
     height: 80px;   
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work for making the header appear and disappear with a fade, however I'm already achieving that with my javascript. See edit. I am just wanting to keep it how it is and ease it in and out...

Comment: As it says in my comment above, you can't transition from "Display: block" to "Display: none" you have to use "Opacity: 0" to "Opacity: 1"

Answer (score 1):

To animate the opacity the element must be visible. So remove the `display:none` and make it fully transparent (`opacity:0`). You can then use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate the `opacity` when the classname changes:

```
.bottomMenu {
    ...
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.bottomMenu.active {
     opacity:1   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oL9ro4gL/6/

Furthermore, you're not restricted to just animating the opacity:

```
.bottomMenu {
    ...
   transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.bottomMenu.active {
    opacity:1;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
    etc...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oL9ro4gL/8/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't animate the `display` property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331353/2241124) and its [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/2241124) for workarounds.